# Representation of a simple messenger application using a database

Tags: mysql, database

In this application there are users, conversations and messages.
More than 2 users could participate in a conversation.

I was thinking this:(---- are relations, CAPITAL_WORDS are entities)

MESSAGE ---- CONVERSATION ---- USER

msg contains sender and the content to be sent;
conversation contains the users that participate in that conversation;

But this is not enough because the sender is a user and there is another link between MSG and USER. If I add this relation I have a problem because the sender should be a user that participate to the conversation.(there is a IS-A relation if I'm not mistaking)

I really don't know how to model this problem. If the conversation was between only 2 users, I would need only MESSAGE and USER. In fact the CONVERSATION entity is pretty strange.

If I eliminate the CONVERSATION from the initial problem I have to add in MESSAGE a field that contains a list of partecipants. But in this way I miss the concept of conversation and then if I have to retrieve the msgs related to a conversation I need a join of all data :) . --> impractical

I will appreciate every suggestion. I don't even know if the database is a good idea for this kind of application. My thought was to do something not too difficult to work with.(keeping in mind that I can lose performance)

Comment: Is it a bulletin board style messaging system or a instant messaging system?

Comment: mainly instant messenger

Comment: Here's a design doc for an IM schema: http://b-i-m.sourceforge.net/designdoc.html. It's a little more involved than what you're looking for atm, but the basic entities are there.